# Why does this solution to the "Circle-ellipse" violate the "Liskov Substition Principle"?

Tags: oop, liskov-substitution-principle

There's a nice example of violating the Liskov Substitution Principle in the [Circle-Ellipse Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem).

Here is how it is phrased (albeit in terms of Rectangle and Square) in [a popular SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584732/33404):

> In mathematics, a `Square` is a `Rectangle`. Indeed it is a specialization of a rectangle. The "is a" makes you want to model this with inheritance. However if in code you made `Square` derive from `Rectangle`, then a `Square` should be usable anywhere you expect a `Rectangle`. This makes for some strange behavior.
>
> Imagine you had `SetWidth` and `SetHeight` methods on your Rectangle base class; this seems perfectly logical. However if your Rectangle reference pointed to a `Square`, then `SetWidth` and `SetHeight` doesn't make sense because setting one would change the other to match it. In this case Square fails the Liskov Substitution Test with `Rectangle` and the abstraction of having Square inherit from Rectangle is a bad one.

**My question is** - Given a solution where we override `setWidth` in `Square` with an implementation that sets both `width` and `height` to the same value, why does it still violate LSP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does violate it, because you promised `setWidth()` would set the width and `setHeight()` will set the height. The `Square` would break this (implicit) promise made by `Rectangle`.

Comment: Thanks. But anyone could argue that there is no such implicit promise, no? Where is it? Is it implied from the method name?

Comment: Yes, it is implied by the name. It is pretty clear for anybody what you mean if you set the height of a rectangle, wouldn't you agree? I guess you could name the method `setWidthAndSometimesHeight()`, and it  would be sort-of ok. But I think you feel that would be super weird..

Comment: Would it be preferable to use a `SquareDecorator` with the `Rectangle` class to provide the `Square` functionality?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a decorator, since it doesn't really preserve the original functionality. I would perhaps just create a `Square` that does not have a common ancestor with `Rectangle` at all. It depends on the use-case.